# Hiduino as a Serial-USB midi coverter

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, softwareserial, midi

I have an Arduino Mega2560 configured to Hiduino, which makes the Arduino a driverless class-compliant MIDI interface.

I am currently converting RS232 serial I/O data to midi data using the 'hairless midi-serial' software running in the background. I am hoping that I can utilize this Hiduino interfacing to send and receive this data in the same fashion, just through the Arduino instead.

I am lead to believe this would require the MIDI library to be used to program the 2560 to understand the serial bytes coming from the controller and converting to the appropriate midi bytes into my program, and vice versa.  I am just getting into programming. Could someone could give an example of how a program could be written to send and receive this data through the Arduino?

Comment: If all things were right, you could send MIDI data from your Hiduino (Serial.write commands) and the inner-hacked chip will do the rest of the job. What's the code you've uploaded? Did you try it with real MIDI ports?

Comment: I've jumped in quite deep these last few weeks, I am sending serial data out to the computer, and back from the computer to my controller successfully. There is a bug however, that i can only confirm occurs with Pro Tools. Once Pro Tools is open, i cannot connect Hiduino i/o to any other application besides Pro Tools without a memory error occuring.